# C# SQLite object custom getter and setter

Tags: c#, sqlite, set

I have a class which is also a table of a database SQLite.

I need to work with dates and I thought the best solution was to work with dates as `integers`, since in `sqlite` i don't have date operations. The problem is the following: I'm saving `DateTime` in my db as `int` using as helper a `DateTime` parameters which is `ignored` by db.

This is my class:

```
public class MYCLASS : Shared
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    [Ignore]
    public DateTime DATA_ORA 
    { 
      get { return DateTime.Parse(this.DATA_ORA_INT.ToString()); } 
      set { this.DATA_ORA_INT = int.Parse(value.ToString("yyyyMMdd")); } 
    }
    private int DATA_ORA_INT { get; set;}
}
```

I'm having the app terminating without any exception when I set the `DATA_ORA` field. Why this code is not working?

**EDIT:**

this is when I got the crush:

```
MYCLASS transazione = new MYCLASS 
{
    ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
    DATA_ORA = DateTime.Now
};
```

Comment: First: Last time I checked SQLite has no problem with DateTime fields what do you mean with _i don't have date operations_, Second: How do you create the integer from a datetime?

Comment: @Steve thanks for replying. The way I create the int is in the code, I format the date into a yyyyMMdd string and from this string I parse an int. By saying the no date operations, I mean that I can't compare dates, or better.. I tryed with <, <=, >, >=, strftime but nothing returned from the query.. Is there another way?

Comment: Yes, I have seen it now, the relevant code was out of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how you create the integer equivalent value of the datetime then, when you need  to revert back to a DateTime from a such formatted field you need something like this

```
public DateTime DATA_ORA 
{ 
   get 
   { 
      // Add a check to return a default if DATA_ORA_INT is not initialized
      return this.DATA_ORA_INT == 0 ? DateTime.Today :
               DateTime.ParseExact(this.DATA_ORA_INT.ToString(), 
                                   "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
   } 
   set { ... }
```

Comment: I tryed it but it's not working, still random crush on new object initialization. I add the code in the question

Comment: Perhaps you need to add some checking in this conversion. If the DATA_ORA_INT contains zero (it's the default for int) then the conversion in the get property will fail. It depends a lot in the order in which you initialize these fields and if you have a constructor that sets a default value for DATA_ORA_INT (ex DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");)

Comment: I had to uninstall-reinstall the app but now it's working, I guess this did it! thanks ^^